Неработает тачпад и клавиатура в Lmde6
Я установил Lmde6 на ноутбук неработают тачпад и клавиатура, но при этом клавиши увеличения яркости и прочие такие работают. В интернете не нашел ничего полезного.
Есть способы?

Ищи и ставь драйвер, если он вообще существует.
